# SQL Server - (AdventureWorks) List the Vendors with no products

Tags: mysql, sql, select, adventureworks

I've been given a question using AdventureWorks to list all the vendors with no products. When I run my SELECT statement nothing is returned. What am I doing wrong? (Answer can only be done using Joins and Unions - No Subqueries)

```
SELECT DISTINCT pv.Name AS 'Vendors'
FROM Purchasing.Vendor pv
INNER JOIN Purchasing.ProductVendor ppv
ON pv.BusinessEntityID = ppv.BusinessEntityID
INNER JOIN Production.Product pp
ON pp.ProductID = ppv.ProductID
WHERE pp.ProductID != ppv.ProductID;
```

Comment: `pp.ProductID = ppv.ProductID` with `pp.ProductID != ppv.ProductID` ... It's natural not to return any row...

Comment: @MEnf I tried that before as well but it returns all vendors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at one too many tables, all ProductVendors have Products. Not all Vendors have ProductVendors.

From there you can simply use a `LEFT JOIN` and look for null records.

```
SELECT DISTINCT v.Name
FROM Purchasing.Vendor v
LEFT JOIN Purchasing.ProductVendor pv ON pv.BusinessEntityID = v.BusinessEntityID
WHERE pv.BusinessEntityID IS NULL
```

Comment: Ahh yes thank you, thank you! I knew I had to be over complicating things.

Answer (score 1):

- Use left join to include cases where there is no product for a "vendor". Inner join will consider only those cases, where a product id exists for a vendor.
- Now, do grouping on a "Vendor" and count the number of products using `COUNT()` function.
- Finally, filter out those vendors where count is zero, using `HAVING` clause

Try the following:

```
SELECT pv.Name AS 'Vendors', 
       Count(pp.ProductID) AS count_products 
FROM Purchasing.Vendor pv
LEFT JOIN Purchasing.ProductVendor ppv
ON pv.BusinessEntityID = ppv.BusinessEntityID
LEFT JOIN Production.Product pp
ON pp.ProductID = ppv.ProductID 
GROUP BY pv.Name 
HAVING count_products = 0;
```

Comment: I get the invalid column name for count_porducts error

Comment: @CameronCole maybe you have wrongly copied my query. It is count_products. There is a typo

Comment: @DerrickMoeller we can very well use the alias in `Having` in MySQL. Read "You can use the alias in GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses to refer to the column"  - [MySQL Doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/problems-with-alias.html)

Comment: Fair enough, I missed the tag.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT pv.Name AS 'Vendors'
  FROM Purchasing.Vendor pv
  INNER JOIN Purchasing.ProductVendor ppv
     ON pv.BusinessEntityID = ppv.BusinessEntityID
  where not exists (SELECT 1 Production.Product pp  Where pp.ProductID = ppv.ProductID)
```

Return all vendors wich donot have any product

Comment: The answer can not be a subquery as per the instructions.